# Assign output of PHP function to a variable

Tags: php, function, return, resultset

Here's my current code:

```
function get_coins() {
    global $conn;
    $new_sql = "SELECT * FROM marketcaps ORDER BY cap DESC LIMIT 25";
    $new_result = $conn->query($new_sql);
    while ($row = $new_result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row["id"];
        $coin = $row["coin"];
        $cap = $row["cap"];
        echo $coin . '~USD,';
    }
}

$coins = get_coins();
```

Here's what I can't figure out:

The line `$coins = get_coins();` is echoing all of the data from my function and I don't understand why.  I know that my function has this line:  `echo $coin . '~USD,';`

But why is it echoing when I add `$coins = get_coins();`?

Shouldn't I have to add this instead?

```
$coins = get_coins();
$echo coins;
```

Basically I don't want to echo anything, I just want to assign the output to a variable.  Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Functions shouldn't `echo` data, they should `return` it.

Comment: You are invoking the function by calling get_coins() hence the function executes and does whatever function is intended to do( in your case echo $coin) what do you try to achieve? Do you want all the result of your query string saved in a variable?

Comment: If I replace `echo` with `return` then it only shows the first MySQL result...

Comment: @NareshKumar Yes, I'm wanting all of the results to be saved in a variable.

Comment: $coins = $new_result->fetch_array(); before foreach and return it after foreach. You can use the same $coins to iterate using loop

Comment: Can you pleas elaborate on how you intend to use the data returned by this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the principles that I have baked in with my solution which returns the full resultset array:

- Don't use `global`, pass `$conn` as a parameter to the function.
- Don't declare single use variables, unless it dramatically improves readability or assists in the debugging process.
- Only query for the specific columns and rows that you intend to process.

Suggested Code:

```
function get_coins($conn): array {
    return $sql
        ->query("SELECT id,coin,cap
                 FROM marketcaps
                 ORDER BY cap DESC
                 LIMIT 25")
        ->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

foreach (get_coins($conn) as $row) {
    // ... reference $row['id'] , $row['coin'] , $row['cap'] during your processes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `return` statement to your function, and as you are dealing with multiple rows, collate them into an array (index by ID).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

```
function get_coins()
{
    global $conn;
    $coins = array();
    $new_sql = "SELECT * FROM marketcaps ORDER BY cap DESC LIMIT 25";
    if( $new_result = $conn->query($new_sql) )
    {
        while( $row = $new_result->fetch_assoc() )
        {
            $coins[ $row["id"] ] = $row["coin"] . '~USD,';
        }
    }
    return ( !empty( $coins ) ) ? $coins : null;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and it does allow me to use a `foreach` statement afterwards to echo everything.  But that still doesn't allow me to assign the output to a variable...

Comment: Yes it does, it returns an array. if `foreach( get_coins() as $coin )` works then `$coins = get_coins();` works too. How are you planing to use this data?

Comment: Seems like you need to return the entire result. So $coins[$iterablevar] = $row;

Comment: `$coins[ $id ]` could be changed to just `$coins[]` if _really_ needed. But there is no benefit unless you're needing a 0,1,2,3 index which `array_values(get_coins())` would get you leaving this function multi purpose.